# Ошибка в тесте: запрос не вернул уникальный результат

Tags: java, rest, асинхронность, testng, mock

Тест не работает, когда запускаю его через IntelliJ IDEA через "Run".
Однако, когда тестирую в ручном режиме, отправляя по одному запросу через Postman, все работает правильно. Также прогонял этот тест через "Degug", так тоже тест завершался успешно, шёл по точкам останова постепенно, видимо, программа выполнялась последовательно.
Думаю, проблема в асинхронности или нескольких connections, хотя я не уверен.

**Полученное исключение:**

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 2

Caused by: jakarta.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2
```

**Код теста:**

```java
private ResultActions performRegister(String body) throws Exception {
        return mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(requestMapping + "/register")
                        .content(body)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

private ResultActions performAuthenticate(String body) throws Exception {
        return mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(requestMapping + "/authenticate")
                .content(body)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

private ResultActions performRefreshToken(String oldRefreshToken) throws Exception {
        return mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post(requestMapping + "/refresh-token")
                .header("Authorization", "Refresh " + oldRefreshToken)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

//тест добавления/изменения refreshToken'ов в БД после регистраций/аутентификаций/рефрешей для 2 пользователей
    @Test
    void test_refresh_token_register_authenticate_2_times() throws Exception {
        List<Token> tokenList;
        String refreshToken;

        //ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ 1
        //регистрация пользователя 1
        MvcResult result1 = performRegister(correctRegisterRequestBody).andReturn();
        tokenList = tokenService.getAllTokens();
        assertEquals(1, tokenList.size());//1 (добавился 1 токен)

        //аутентификация 1 пользователя 1
        MvcResult result2 = performAuthenticate(correctAuthenticateRequestBody).andReturn();
        refreshToken = getRefreshTokenFromResult(result2);
        tokenList = tokenService.getAllTokens();
        assertEquals(2, tokenList.size());//2 (добавился 1 токен)

        //рефреш 1 пользователя 1
        MvcResult result3 = performRefreshToken(refreshToken).andReturn();
        tokenList = tokenService.getAllTokens();
        assertEquals(2, tokenList.size());//2 (заменился 1 токен)

        //аутентификация 2 пользователя 1
        MvcResult result4 = performAuthenticate(correctAuthenticateRequestBody).andReturn();
        tokenList = tokenService.getAllTokens();
        assertEquals(3, tokenList.size());//3 (добавился 1 токен)

        //ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ 2
        //регистрация пользователя 2
        MvcResult result5 = performRegister(correctRegisterRequestBody2).andReturn();
        tokenList = tokenService.getAllTokens();
        assertEquals(4, tokenList.size());//4 (добавился 1 токен)

        //аутентификация 1 пользователя 2
        MvcResult result6 = performAuthenticate(correctAuthenticateRequestBody2).andReturn();
        refreshToken = getRefreshTokenFromResult(result6);
        tokenList = tokenService.getAllTokens();
        assertEquals(5, tokenList.size());//5 (добавился 1 токен)

        //рефреш 1 пользователя 2
        MvcResult result7 = performRefreshToken(refreshToken).andReturn();
        tokenList = tokenService.getAllTokens();
        assertEquals(5, tokenList.size());//5 (заменился 1 токен)

        //аутентификация 2 пользователя 2
        MvcResult result8 = performAuthenticate(correctAuthenticateRequestBody2).andReturn();
        tokenList = tokenService.getAllTokens();
        assertEquals(6, tokenList.size());//6 (добавился 1 токен)
    }
```

**Логи:**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/v1/auth/register
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"161"]
             Body = {
    "name": "Ivan2023",
    "email": "ivanov123@gmail.com",
    "phoneNumber": "89138005544",
    "birthday": "2001-11-28",
    "password": "hardPassword123"
}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.shulpov.spots_app.auth.controllers.AuthenticationController
           Method = com.shulpov.spots_app.auth.controllers.AuthenticationController#register(RegisterRequest, BindingResult)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 201
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"id":100,"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6W3siYXV0aG9yaXR5IjoiUk9MRV9VU0VSIn1dLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Iml2YW5vdjEyM0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiJpdmFub3YxMjNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjk3OTY0NTE4LCJleHAiOjE2OTgwNTA5MTh9.zIa27WblbJFAPH0rUKhnFoWKFkB_r1J_2WibSpW-F8I","refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJpdmFub3YxMjNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjk3OTY0NTE4LCJleHAiOjE2OTg1NjkzMTh9.8a6KB6qkb5mf1tMjv-zEdY84PJpyZczvDNoTKLAR-SY"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/v1/auth/authenticate
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"73"]
             Body = {
    "email": "ivanov123@gmail.com",
    "password": "hardPassword123"
}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = com.shulpov.spots_app.auth.controllers.AuthenticationController
           Method = com.shulpov.spots_app.auth.controllers.AuthenticationController#authenticate(AuthenticationRequest)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"id":100,"access_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdXRob3JpdGllcyI6W3siYXV0aG9yaXR5IjoiUk9MRV9VU0VSIn1dLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6Iml2YW5vdjEyM0BnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJzdWIiOiJpdmFub3YxMjNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjk3OTY0NTE4LCJleHAiOjE2OTgwNTA5MTh9.zIa27WblbJFAPH0rUKhnFoWKFkB_r1J_2WibSpW-F8I","refresh_token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJpdmFub3YxMjNAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWF0IjoxNjk3OTY0NTE4LCJleHAiOjE2OTg1NjkzMTh9.8a6KB6qkb5mf1tMjv-zEdY84PJpyZczvDNoTKLAR-SY"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 2

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:906)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at com.shulpov.spots_app.auth.filters.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilterInternal(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:351)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(MockMvc.java:201)
    at com.shulpov.spots_app.AuthTests.performRefreshToken(AuthTests.java:220)
    at com.shulpov.spots_app.AuthTests.test_refresh_token_register_authenticate_few_times(AuthTests.java:335)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 2
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:382)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:235)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy154.findByValue(Unknown Source)
    at com.shulpov.spots_app.auth.token.TokenService.getTokenByValue(TokenService.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at com.shulpov.spots_app.auth.token.TokenService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.getTokenByValue(<generated>)
    at com.shulpov.spots_app.auth.services.AuthenticationService.refreshToken(AuthenticationService.java:136)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at com.shulpov.spots_app.auth.services.AuthenticationService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.refreshToken(<generated>)
    at com.shulpov.spots_app.auth.controllers.AuthenticationController.refreshToken(AuthenticationController.java:97)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003)
    ... 129 more
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 2
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:466)
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.getSingleResult(QuerySqmImpl.java:1062)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:193)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 176 more

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: https://github.com/ShulV/Xmap/blob/main/src/test/java/com/shulpov/spots_app/AuthTests.java

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тексту ошибки, у вас создаются дубли, и там, где ожидается одна запись, из БД возращается 2 записи.

Скорее всего это из за генерации токена:

```
Jwts
    .builder()
    .setClaims(extraClaims)
    .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
    .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
    .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiration))
    .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
    .compact();
```

При вызове тестов значение времени одинаковое.

Comment: Я думал об этом. Возможно у меня токен генерируется с одинаковым значением не в одном месте. Из идей у меня пока что только генерировать токен с солью, так число коллизий будет крайне маленьким. Плюс эта проблема возникает только, если в моменте токен генерится с одними и теми же данными.

Comment: Думаю, Ваш ответ очень помог мне. Я добавил один клэйм перед JWT билдером:
extraClaims.put("creatingDate", System.currentTimeMillis());

Так же добавил UNIQUE на поле value для таблицы с токенами.
Этот вариант пока что самый простой.
Если не будет ответа лучше, баллы Вам.

Comment: Судя документации claim или payload носит полезную информацию. Для решения данной проблемы рекомендую использовать .setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).

Comment: Sets the JWT Claims jti (JWT ID) value. A null value will remove the property from the Claims.
The value is a CaSe-SenSiTiVe unique identifier for the JWT. If specified, this value MUST be assigned in a manner that ensures that there is a negligible probability that the same value will be accidentally assigned to a different data object. The ID can be used to prevent the JWT from being replayed.